# Tab cycling back to first tabbable DOM element instead of address bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accessibility

I have a tree component at the end of the DOM that handles keydown events so that the tree is navigable via arrow keys. I don't have any cases that respond to a "Tab" press, but the default behavior seems to send the focus to the first tabbable element in the DOM, rather than shifting focus to the browser.

I am unsure if this would qualify as a keyboard trap, as the focus is able to pass through all available DOM elements, and users can still access the browser via Ctrl+L/Cmd+L.

If I add a tabbable item after this tree component, such as a , shifting focus from the tree moves it to the button, and another Tab press will bring the focus into the browser.

Currently, I am not able to add a tabbable element to the end of the DOM that would make sense with the UI design. My main question: Does this looping back to the first element in the DOM from the last element introduce a Keyboard Trap concern? If so, is there any way I could get a Tab keypress to move the focus into the browser via Javascript?

Edit: This behavior was observed on Chrome on a Windows VM.
We're using jQuery to handle the keydown events, but removing the Tab case still cycles the focus back to the top:

```
$.on({
            mousedown: {
               //...handle mousedown event
            },
            keydown: function (e) {

                var newFocus;

                if (e.keyCode === keyCodes.Tab) {
                    // NOTE: tried removing this check entirely before, still cycles back to the first element rather than exiting focus to the browser
                    // Perhaps cycling to the first tabbable element is default jQuery keydown behavior?
                    e.preventDefault();         // Prevent tab nav from bubbling-up and triggering focusin
                    newFocus = e.shiftKey ?
                        getPreviousTabTarget() :
                        getNextTabTarget();
                } else if (arrowKeyCodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
                    //...handle arrow key keydown event
                } else if (e.keyCode === keyCodes.Enter) {
                    //...handle Enter keydown event
                } else if (e.keyCode === keyCodes.Space) {
                    //...handle Space keydown event
                }

                if (newFocus) {

                    newFocus.focus();
                }
            },
            focusin: function (e) {

                if (!currentItem) {

                    currentItem = jqElement.children()[0];
                }

                if (currentItem) {

                    currentItem.focus();
                }
            }
        });
```

Edit 2: This example page from W3 showing a jQuery keydown/keyup event handler does pass the tab into the browser properly. There is definitely something I missed here. Thanks @QuentinC for the sanity check! And thanks to everyone for your responses.

Comment: Sounds like your "tree component" is handling/controlling the tab.

Comment: Do you have an example page showing the problem ? Can you also tell us on which browser and OS you have observed that behavior ? At first glance, it looks like a bug of the browser, but without any example nor knowing about which browser/OS you are talking about, it's hard to say more.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.